# How do I debug an Android app on a real phone in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I want to make an Android app and debug the app on my phone.

I already have the developers settings and I already have the USB mode setting to 'MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)', so I can access the file system on explorer.

My problems are:

1. I can't see 'debug mode' on my phone.
2. And I can't select my phone on visual studio because I don't have that option by the start button.

Visual studio 2017
Android version: 6.0.1

Comment: Which phone do you have? Sometimes the debugging settings are hidden until you perform a certain set of actions. Usually you go to Settings -> About Phone -> Look for Build Number -> Tap it a bunch of times until developer settings are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In developers settings you have to enable USB Debugging
- Do you have adb tools installed on your computer ? You have to download it on internet, you can also check when you plug your device in the tools installer can be on the phone

Comment: I'd add that a lot of times you need to install the drivers for your phone onto your computer.  I'm not 100% sure if this is still the case, but a couple years ago VS wouldn't recognize samsung phones until you did.

Comment: i have adb.exe.

Comment: @olifonmistie And what if you install it, reboot, then plug your phone in with USB Debugging enabled ?